# I want to animate an UIImageView & during animation I want to recognize event on it

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

When am animating a UIImageView it doesn't send event during it is animating, but when it finishes its animation, that time it is able to send event, I'v tried UIButton too.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to include the UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction option when invoking the animation:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration 
                          delay:0 
                        options:(UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction)
                     <snip>];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
    [animation setDelegate:self];   
    [animation setType:kCATransitionFade];
    [animation setDuration:0.0];// try 0.1 also
    [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:
                                  kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
    [[yourImageView layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"transitionViewAnimation"];//Try   self.view insted of yourImageView if you want to animate whole view
```